# filter html by span tag inside td in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have an external dropdown form which have a values of correct and incorrect, whenever incorrect is chosen a ajax post will run and will generate a span inside td for incorrect values. What I need is that datatables should filter out incorrect by checking span inside td.

HTML:

```
<select id="filter">
 <option value="correct">Correct</option>
 <option value="incorrect">Incorrect</option>
</select>

//Data Tables
<table id="data">
   <thead>
      <tr>Word</tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr><td>Cat</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Dog</td></tr>
      <tr><td><span="wrong-spelling">Dogr<td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var dtTable = $('#data').dataTable( {
    "sDom": '<"H"lr>t<"F"ip>',
    "bSort": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "iDisplayStart": 0,
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                     {"sType": "string"},
         {"sType": "string"},
                     {"sType": "string"}
        ]       
});      


  $("#filter").change(function(){
     //Ajax Post request to check spelling and will insert span on misspelled words
     dtTable.fnFilter('span');
  });
});
```

On #filter change, when incorrect is chosen it should only filter rows with span class wrong-spelling